# Make another copy of a plugin and install it

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm trying to make another copy of this plugin [SyncFields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/syncfields/)
It contains just one file syncfields.php, So I tried to edit it and edit the functions with another name but it didn't work
It appeared in the plugins page and activated it , but didn't find it in the menu 
I don't know what what did I missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you haven't changed all IDs inside that plugin.

For example, when you register admin menu page, you have to pass its slug, which is unique identifier for that page. If you register two pages with the same slug, only one will be visible.

It's the same with registering options, custom post types, and so on...

So renaming only functions won't solve the problem...